# Parsing timestamps takes a very long time

Tags: r, performance

I have written a function to make a matrix with year, month and day columns generated from a epoch timestamp (in milliseconds). However this function is so incredibly slow that it's useless for the 7+ million rows of data that I have.

Is there a way to parse a millisecond timestamp to year, month and day that is a lot faster than this?

```
timestamp_to_ymd <- function(data){
  result <- matrix(nrow = length(data), ncol = 3)

  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(data), style = 3)
  for (i in 1:length(data)){
    posixtime <- as.POSIXlt(data[i]/1000, origin="1970-01-01")

    result[i,1] <- posixtime$year + 1900
    result[i,2] <- posixtime$mon + 1
    result[i,3] <- posixtime$mday
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  }
  close(pb)
  return(result)
}
```

Generate testdata:

```
testdata <- 1483225200000:1483228200000
```

Comment: Please checkout packages specific to time-series data like `zoo`, `xts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a loop, those functions can handle vectors:

```
result <- matrix(nrow = length(data), ncol = 3)
posixtime <- as.POSIXlt(data/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
result[,1] <- posixtime$year + 1900
result[,2] <- posixtime$mon + 1
result[,3] <- posixtime$mday
result
```

Comment: Oh yes, very nice he worked out the function in mere seconds!